Creating a matrix/system of equations to solve car distribution in three cities
A car rental company has offices in three cities: $A, B$ and $C$. Of the cars rented in $A$, $60\%$ are returned in $A$, $30\%$ are returned in $B$, and $10\%$ in C. Of the cars rented in $B$, $30\%$ are returned in $A$, 50% are returned in $B$, and $20\%$ in $C$.  Of the cars rented in $C$, $60\%$ are returned in $A$, $10\%$ in $B$ and $30\%$ in C. The company has a total of $120$ cars. How should the company divide the cars between $A$, $B$ and $C$ so that the number of cars returned in each city is equal to the number of cars rented?
I was thinking of making a system of equations and a matrix, but the only equation I have is this: $$A + B + C = 120$$
And the matrix I came up with is this:
\begin{pmatrix}
0.6& 0.3& 0.6& 0\\
0.3& 0.5& 0.1& 0\\
0.1& 0.2& 0.3& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
It’s supposed to represent the amount of cars in A, B and C after being returned.
However, I am stuck and don’t know what to do. Gauss-elimination on the matrix didn’t give me anything. What do I do?

You are on the right track. Assume that for each unit of time (say a week for example), every single car is always rented out to someone and then returned. Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ denote the number of cars at locations $A$, $B$, and $C$ currently. The subscript $a_0$, $b_0$, and $c_0$ means cars located at $A$, $B$, and $C$ at week zero, $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$ at week one, and so on.
After a single week of rentals, the number of cars at locations $A$, $B$, and $C$ will be $$\begin{pmatrix}{a_1\\b_1\\c_1}\end{pmatrix}=T \begin{pmatrix}{a_0\\b_0\\c_0}\end{pmatrix},$$ where $T$ is the matrix in your question. This is usually called a transition matrix.
If, for example, you start out with an equal number of cars at each location, $\mathbf{x}_0=\begin{bmatrix}40&40&40\end{bmatrix}^T$, after the first week you would end up with $$T\mathbf{x}_0=\begin{pmatrix}0.6&0.3&0.6\\0.3&0.5&0.1\\0.1&0.2&0.3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}40\\40\\40\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}60\\36\\24\end{pmatrix}$$ 60 cars at location $A$, 36 cars at location $B$, and 24 cars at location $C$.
Your task is to find a starting distribution of cars in the three locations, $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}a_0&b_0&c_0\end{bmatrix}^T$, such that the distribution does not change after the first week (or any subsequent week for that matter). In other words, you are looking for $\mathbf{x}$ such that $$T\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}.$$ This is called an eigenvalue problem (with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$). The matrix $T$ has one relevant real non-negative eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ with corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1\end{bmatrix}^T$. Scaling up to the total number of cars, $a+b+c=120$, we can multiply $\mathbf{v}$ by 20 to get $$\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}60\\40\\20\end{pmatrix},$$ such that  $$T\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}0.6&0.3&0.6\\0.3&0.5&0.1\\0.1&0.2&0.3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}60\\40\\20\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}60\\40\\20\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{x}.$$ In other words, you should place 60 cars at location $A$, 40 cars at location $B$, and 20 cars at location $C$ to maintain balance.
